# How to grab a specific SHA from the git log output

Tags: git, import, cygwin, logging, sha

Executing the following command `git log --before "Feb 01 2011"` returns all of the commits from before the specified date, including their SHA
I'm trying to write a cygwin script that syncs my head to the last commit of a specific month, without me having to find and enter the SHA myself.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `rev-list` with the same options as you would pass to log, plus `-n 1` to return just the first one.

```
sha1=$(git rev-list --before "Feb 01 2011" -n 1 HEAD)
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash on linux the following works, I think it should also work on cygwin:

```
git checkout $(git log --before='Feb 01 2011' -n1 | head -n 1 |sed s/commit\ //)
```

It may be a good idea to immediately create a branch when you do that

```
git checkout $(git log --before='Feb 01 2011' -n1 | head -n 1 |sed s/commit\ //) -b 2011-02
```

Or alternatively if you intend to create a script tagging is perhaps a better option. Eg:

```
git checkout $(git log --before='Feb 01 2011' -n1 | head -n 1 |sed s/commit\ //)
git tag 2011-01
```